# What's the difference between Lucene's FloatField and FloatDocValuesField?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

For storing a float type in a document these are two options with apparently overlapping functionalities. What's there difference? (I'm using lucene-solr 4.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FloatDocValuesField` is a `DocValues` field.  The idea is to provide values for a document that can be retrieved quickly, without having to resort to fetching the document from storage, for use, for example, in scoring (See: [`AtomicReader.getNumericDocValues`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html#getNumericDocValues%28java.lang.String%29)).

Generally, you should stick to `FloatField`, etc. unless you need the functionality provided by the DocValues fields.

For further reading: [Introducing Lucene Index Doc Values](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/10/27/introducing-lucene-index-doc-values/), or this [brief description of it as pertains to Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues).